# Select node from XML and Create a new XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I m trying to strip my XML and keep only nodes which are in the String Keep array

Input XML is

```
 <Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Address>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <Name>Lucy</Name>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <Address>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Output I need is

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Address>
     <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <Address>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

My code is as below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xDoc.Load(XML_Path);
           // xDoc.Load();
            XmlNodeList xNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("Employees/Employee");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(docNode);

            XmlNode employeesNode = doc.CreateElement("Employees");
            doc.AppendChild(employeesNode);
            string s =null;
            string keep = "EmpId,Sex,Address/Zip";
            string[] strArr = keep.Split(',');
            foreach(XmlNode xN in xNodes)
            {
                XmlNode employeeNode = doc.CreateElement("Employee");
                employeesNode.AppendChild(employeeNode);

                foreach (string str in strArr)
                {
                    XmlNode xNod = xN.SelectSingleNode(str);
                    employeeNode.AppendChild(xNod);

                }

            }
            richTextBox1.Text = doc.ToString();

        }
```

I get a weird error in inner foreach loop it wont add the new node can anyone tell me what wrong am i doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using Linq to Xml, the code will be much succint.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(XML_Path)
    string keep = "EmpId,Sex,Address,Zip";
    string[] strArr = keep.Split(',');

    var nodesToDelete = xDoc.Root.Descendants("Employee")
        .SelectMany(e => e.Descendants()
                          .Where(a => !strArr.Contains(a.Name.ToString())));

    foreach (var node in nodesToDelete.ToList())
        node.Remove();

    richTextBox1.Text = xDoc.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying to make this generic.. so its possible that there will be more nodes then Name Address/Country etc which has to be removed.. String Keep is actually a textBox.Text which comes from winform and this is what will define what I need to keep.

Comment: @user2920743, check the updated answer, just put the nodes you want to keep without the slash separator

Answer (score 0):

How about using XDocument ?

Bellow code gives you the required output.

```
string xmlString =
            @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
            <Employees>
              <Employee>
                <EmpId>1</EmpId>
                <Name>Sam</Name>
                <Sex>Male</Sex>
                <Address>
                  <Country>USA</Country>
                  <Zip>95220</Zip>
                </Address>
              </Employee>
              <Employee>
                <EmpId>2</EmpId>
                <Name>Lucy</Name>
                <Sex>Female</Sex>
                <Address>
                  <Country>USA</Country>
                  <Zip>95220</Zip>
                </Address>
              </Employee>
            </Employees>
            ";

        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xmlDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

        foreach (var employee in xmlDoc.Descendants("Employee"))
        {
            employee.Descendants("Name").First().Remove();

            employee.Descendants("Address").First().Descendants("Country").First().Remove();
        }

        MessageBox.Show(xmlDoc.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying to make this generic.. so its possible that there will be more nodes then Name Address/Country etc which has to be removed.. String Keep is actually a textBox.Text which comes from winform and this is what will define what I need to keep. So I am not sure about which Tag's I have to remove but I know which I have to keep..

Comment: Instead of doing a remove there is there a way I can keep the tag's I want to keep ?

Answer (score 0):

You could go with something like this:

```
XmlDocument source = new XmlDocument();
source.LoadXml(xmldata);

var keep = new[] {"EmpId", "Sex", "Address/Zip"};
foreach (XmlElement employee in source.SelectNodes("/Employees/Employee"))
foreach (XmlElement child in employee.SelectNodes(".//*"))
{
    if(keep.Any(i => i.StartsWith(child.Name) || i.EndsWith(child.Name)))
        continue;

    child.ParentNode.RemoveChild(child);
}
Console.WriteLine(source.OuterXml);
```

However, as your `keep` array could be changed and different scenarios could be required, you should try go with a XSLT transformation.